# Custom overlay for UIImagePickerController shows warning in the console

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

In my app I need to use `custom camera`. For that I am using overlay with custom buttons.
The problem is whenever I launch the `custom camera`, I am getting the following warning in the console.

> Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty
>   snapshot. Ensure your view has been rendered at least once before
>   snapshotting or snapshot after screen updates.

Can someone help me out on this?.
Thanks in advance.